# Horizontal Tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement horizontally scrollable tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703857/how-to-implement-horizontally-scrollable-tabs)

I would like to implement tabs in an app that essentially also allows swiping between two screens.   A good example would be in the App section in the Google Play store.  There are horizontal scrollable tabs up top and they move as the screen scrolls.

I am targeting Android 4.0 with this but need to make it backwards compatible.

I am obviously not asking anyone to write the entirety of code on this, I simply am looking for a tutorial somewhere, or advice on how to go about starting this.   The Dev site show exactly what I want here: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

But doesn't show HOW to do this (or at least make it visibly clear); it only says that's its good practice to do.

Comment: ^ That along with 104254252 other duplicates...

Comment: Yes, but that is older implementation. I believe they have new recommendation now then what that shows?

Comment: An older (???) implementation that works just fine and follow the rules. What's up with that about old code anyways?

Comment: As in, I thought Google deprecated one method in favor of another. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this API, I use it and its very easy to implement

[ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Comment: Is this free for commercial use?

Comment: its open source, plenty of applications in the market use it

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by using [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) class. In order to make it backward compatible take a look at the [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) project; there you will find [examples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java) on how to implement this kind of design pattern and make it work even on Android 1.6.

Also, as Alex said, you can take a look at the [ViewPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) project of the same developer if you don't want to care about an action bar.

Comment: [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) is a possibility too, if the OP doesn't care about the action bar at all.

Comment: You are right Alex. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No point in importing the entire `ActionBarSherlock` library for no reason... that thing is huge :)

Comment: I never even considered it, but for these two activities, I wouldn't necessarily need an ActionBar.